# PredictionIO deploy Error with spark cluster on yarn

Tags: predictionio

I hava install predictionIO with a spark clsuter on yarn mode. But when I use pio deploy a engine ,seening following error: how can i fix it ?

`[ERROR] [OneForOneStrategy] Wrong FS: file:/home/hadoop/MyClassification/engine.json, expected: hdfs://nameservice1`

`[ERROR] [OneForOneStrategy] Wrong FS: file:/home/hadoop/MyClassification/engine.json, expected: hdfs://nameservice1`

**Here is my pio-env.sh file:**

```sh
# PredictionIO Main Configuration
SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/spark
ES_CONF_DIR=$PIO_HOME/vendors/elasticsearch-5.6.2/config
HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/usr/lib/hadoop/etc/hadoop
HBASE_CONF_DIR=/opt/app/hbase/conf

# Filesystem paths where PredictionIO uses as block storage.
PIO_FS_BASEDIR=$HOME/.pio_store
PIO_FS_ENGINESDIR=$PIO_FS_BASEDIR/engines
PIO_FS_TMPDIR=$PIO_FS_BASEDIR/tmp

# Default is to use PostgreSQL
PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_METADATA_NAME=pio_meta
PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_METADATA_SOURCE=ELASTICSEARCH

PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_EVENTDATA_NAME=pio_event
PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_EVENTDATA_SOURCE=HBASE

PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_MODELDATA_NAME=pio_model
PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_MODELDATA_SOURCE=HDFS

# Elasticsearch Example
PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_ELASTICSEARCH_TYPE=elasticsearch
PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=localhost
PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_ELASTICSEARCH_PORTS=9200
PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_ELASTICSEARCH_SCHEMES=http
PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_ELASTICSEARCH_CLUSTERNAME=pio
PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_ELASTICSEARCH_HOME=$PIO_HOME/vendors/elasticsearch-5.6.2

# Local File System Example
PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_HDFS_TYPE=hdfs
PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_HDFS_PATH=hdfs://nameservice1/user/hadoop/mymodels

# HBase Example
PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_HBASE_TYPE=hbase
PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_HBASE_HOME=/opt/app/hbase
```

Comment: Don't use image. Rather, insert code in some code blocks

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug in predictionio, but had been fixed in [1094de8](https://github.com/apache/predictionio/commit/b2ef98369542ddd6cd8b783574cdb9d62081a8bf)

Comment: Please add some additional information to your answer.